# C# Function parameter implementing abstract class and multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, parameter-passing, multiple-inheritance, abstract

Consider the following structure in C#:

```
interface I1
interface I2

abstract class A
- class A1 : A
  - class A11 : A1, I1
  - class A12 : A1, I2
- class A2 : A
  - class A21 : A2, I1
  - class A22 : A2, I2
```

Now I have a class B which takes an argument in the constructor. That argument must be a class that is somehow derived from A and implements the interface I2, i.e. it can be a class of type A12 or A22, but not A11 or A21. How can I define that parameter? Furthermore, I want to store the parameter later as a property in B (for later usage).

I cannot redefine A as an interface because it provides a lot of virtual methods. Neither can I skip the tree-like inheritance scheme, because A1 and A2 provide a number of specific methods that are used elsewhere (not in B). So, all I need to handle in B is stuff from A and I2.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but instead of A being an abstract class, consider making it an interface and implementing its methods as extension methods.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: Because I need to access properties and methods of A in class B.

Comment: How do you want to use the passed object? as class A or as Interface I2?

Comment: @Alexandr Mihalciuc: Both at the same time. Otherwise it would be easy to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I define that parameter?

You can't, basically. Not in a constructor.

The closest you could come to would be to create a static generic method returning a B:

```
public static B CreateInstance<T>(T item) where T : A, I2
```

You can't do this in a constructor because constructors can't be generic.

However, then if you need to *store* that value, you would need to choose to have a field of type `A` or `I2`, and cast when you need to.

Of course, you could make `B` generic as per Enigmativity's answer - but that may have other implications elsewhere. If you want a non-generic `B`, you could potentially have both:

```
public abstract class B
{
    // Common operations which don't depend on the constructor parameter
}

public class B<T> : B where T : A, I2
{
    public B(T item)
    {
    }
}
```

This starts to get pretty complex, of course.

Alternatively, you *could* skip compile-time checking, and just check at execution time:

```
public class B
{
    private readonly A item;

    public B(A item)
    {
        if (!(item is I2))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

While compile-time safety is preferable in general, it *may* be that it's not worth the extra hoops you need to go through in this case. It really depends on what you're doing with the type.

Comment: You could define a generic class however - like Enigmativity's answer.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I was updating my answer to include that possibility, and other options around it. Making the type generic is choice which is forced on *all* users of the class, not just those constructing an instance - that's a burden which may be more than is justified.

Comment: That's true - I tried to build up a class library once which used quite a lot of generic classes that built on other generics. I quickly learnt that actually generics can be painful. You can have an upvote too :P

Comment: I've tried the different solutions, and it seems to me that using runtime checking is the way I will use. It's not really beautiful, but it seems to work with the least hassle. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
class B<T> where T : A, I2
{
    public B(T parameter)
    {
        this.Property = parameter;
    }

    public T Property { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it seems to cause trouble with WinForms. Actually, in the real problem, class B is a Form (forgot to mention that). I end up with a construct like "partial class B<T> : Form where T : A, I2" which seems to kill the designer somewhere.

Comment: @HansD.Ampf - Yes, being a Windows Form would kill this. Well actually, it doesn't directly kill this. It would still work, but you would, as you found out, lose designer support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to create instance of A1, A2, A12, A22 classes, if not then you can make them abstract and restrict the constructor parameter for only classes that implement them

```
class B
    {
        public B(A11 a12)
        {

        }

        public B(A22 a12)
        {

        }   

    }
```

Comment: That was my first attempt. However, that means loosing quite some flexibility as there is (in the real problem) much, much more than only A12 and A22. And I don't want to rewrite B everytime I add another item to the tree below A.